# combine two columns based on a condition - python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame with two columns
and I would like to create a new column based on this condition :

- if the value of y is -1 take the value of x
- if the value of x is -1 take the value of y

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['day', 'day', 'night', '-1', '-1', '-1'],
                   'y': ['-1', '-1', '-1', 'night', 'day', 'day']})
df
```

I have tried the following but I got a None and NaN output

```
def func(x):
    if (x['y'] == -1):
        return x['x']
    elif (x['x'] == -1):
        return x['y']

df = df.assign(z=df.apply(func, axis=1))
df
```

and

```
conditions = [
    (df['y'] == -1),
    (df['x'] == -1),
]

choices = [df['x'],df['y']]
df['z1'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
df
```

the expected result should be like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['day', 'day', 'night', '-1', '-1', '-1'],
                   'y': ['-1', '-1', '-1', 'night', 'day', 'day'],
                   'z':['day','day','night','night','day','day']})
df
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is fine, except one moment: you are comparing with integer in `func`, but you have strings in your dataframe, consider to rewrite it like this (add quotes around -1):

```
def func(x):
    if (x['y'] == '-1'):
        return x['x']
    elif (x['x'] == '-1'):
        return x['y']
```

or use integers in the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['day', 'day', 'night', -1, -1, -1],
                   'y': [-1, -1, -1, 'night', 'day', 'day']})
```

but not both at the same time of course.

You can also consider casting types or comparing with multiple values `n in [-1, '-1']` if it suits your needs better.